# Ubuntu & Mac OSX (install Ubuntu Touch to tablet, from Mac platform)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, system-installation, macbook, macosx, nexus-7

I know this has probably been asked many times over but here goes: I have a **MacBook Pro 15"** and an **Nexus 7 (2013)** tablet.

I want to install **Ubuntu** (Touch) onto the Nexus but I don't have Ubuntu on my Mac. *What I need to know is this, what do I need to run Ubuntu on my Mac, either by partitioning the hard drive (I do not want to wipe my OSX!) or by using an external HDD as the Ubuntu drive.*

I then want to install *Ubuntu Touch* onto the Nexus 7. *Yes, I'm asking a lot especially as I have no experience with Ubuntu and hacking. Can you help please?*

Comment: I run Ubuntu within a Virtual Machine on my MacBook, you could try this?  Alternatively you can just boot it from a USB Live disk if you don't want to install and configure VMS :P.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu on an external HDD by going into the install, selecting "Something Else" choosing /dev/sdb or whatever your HDD is mounted as in the drop down menu, making one big partition as EXT4 , then choosing "/" in the mount point drop down menu. Instructions for Ubuntu on the Nexus are on here; http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reply. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Okay. If you can't get it to work, I will provide photographs.

Comment: Oh, do I need to format the external drive as it'll be formatted for OSX?

Comment: No, you can partition anyway. Ubuntu can mount literally EVERYTHING. :P

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. I'll let you know how I get on. Cheers.